# reorder not setting the shipping method used last time

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, shipping-methods, reorder

I want to reorder a product programmatically. For this I'd followed the answer: [Magento - Programmatically reorder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122181/725306). But I'm getting error message

> Please specify a shipping method.

Why isn't it setting the shipping method used earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know why isn't it setting the **shipping method** used last time but below is the code I needed to add in order to make this work:

```
$reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->setShippingMethod($order->getShippingMethod())
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
```